# Spring Batch Job Execution Listener - Access details of sub-jobs defined by JobStep

Tags: spring-batch

I have a job(parent job) of jobs(child). In the jobexecution listener of parent job, I want to access all the details(job name, step names, read/write count etc.) of each child jobs. How can I achieve this?

Below is example code. In afterJob method of parentJobExecutionListener, I want to send an email(already have code for it), containing complete details of JOB1 and JOB2. Below code in afterJob method prints details of JOB-STEP1 and JOB-STEP2. How can I access details of child jobs(JOB1 and JOB2) and their steps?

```
public class ParentJobConfig {

    @Bean
    public Job job1() {
        Job job = jobBuilderFactory.get("JOB1")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(step11())
                .next(step12())
                .build();
        return job;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job2() {
        Job job = jobBuilderFactory.get("JOB2")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(step21())
                .next(step22())
                .build();
        return job;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step jobStep1() {
        Step step = stepBuilderFactory.get("JOB-STEP1")
                .job(job1())
                .parametersExtractor(new DefaultJobParametersExtractor())
                .build();
        return step;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step jobStep2() {
        Step step = stepBuilderFactory.get("JOB-STEP2")
                .job(job2())
                .parametersExtractor(new DefaultJobParametersExtractor())
                .build();
        return step;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job parentJob() {
        Job job = jobBuilderFactory.get("PARENT-JOB")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(jobStep1())
                .next(jobStep2())
                .listener(parentJobExecutionListener())
                .build();
        return job;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobExecutionListener parentJobExecutionListener() {
        return new ParentJobExecutionListener ();
    }
}

public class ParentJobExecutionListener extends JobExecutionListenerSupport {

    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        List<StepExecution> stepExecutions = (List<StepExecution>) jobExecution.getStepExecutions();
        Collection<StepExecution> stepExecutions = jobExecution.getStepExecutions();
        for (StepExecution stepExecution : stepExecutions) {
            System.out.println("Step Name: " + stepExecution.getStepName());
            System.out.println("Read Count: " + stepExecution.getReadCount());
            System.out.println("Skip Count: " + stepExecution.getSkipCount());
            System.out.println("Write Count: " + stepExecution.getWriteCount());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an obvious way to get access to the child job executions created here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/d8fc58338d3b059b67b5f777adc132d2564d7402/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/step/job/JobStep.java#L119 (Only the status is reflected on the step execution).

What you can do is use a job explorer in your listener and query the repository for child job executions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would use JobExplorer for the same. In the same flow, can I run jobStep2() only when some condition is true? I have DB table in which it's specified on which dates JOB2 should run. The PARENT-JOB will be scheduled from crontab to run daily. JOB1 will run daily. But for JOB2, I need to query database, check if current date is one of the dates JOB2 should run, then only run the JOB-STEP2, otherwise skip it yet PARENT-JOB should be considered COMPLETED. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I also have a different question related to this design, which I have posted at I also have a different question related to this design, which I have posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63978036/job-of-jobs-run-jobs-as-sub-jobs-as-well-as-independently Would appreciate suggestions on that as well.
Would appreciate suggestions on that as well.