# Job of Jobs - Run Jobs as sub-jobs, as well as independently

Tags: spring-batch

I have a ParentJob with below 2 JobSteps:

1. JobStep1

   - Job1 - Step11 -> Step12
2. JobStep2

   - Job2 - Step21 -> Step22

I would have had a single Job with all the steps. But I have scenarios when I would have to run Step11 & Step12, and Step21 & Step22 independently. This is the reason I have included them in Job1 and Job2, and then calling Job1 and Job2 from ParentJob.
All of these jobs(ParentJob, Job1 and Job2) have RunIdIncrementer associated with them. When ParentJob runs, all the jobs run with same run.id paramater(RunIdIncrementer of child jobs i.e. Job1 and Job2 doesn't work in this scenario, which is obvious).

The problem I am facing is that, for e.g. on first run, all jobs run with run id as 1. Then if Job2 is run independently, it would run with run.id 2. Now, when ParentJob is run again, it runs with run.id 2, and Job1 runs fine, but Job2 gives JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException. I understand that RunIdIncrementer of Job1 and Job2 will not work. But, is there a way to achieve what I want to do?

The solution in my mind is to have my custom JobParametersIncrementer, generating run.id unique every time it is run. Probably, run.id as current time in millis. Still I prefer RunIdIncrementer as run.id generated by it looks cleaner.

Would also appreciate any suggestions on design change, if that's required.

Comment: I don't see why you need a job of jobs. I would use a single job with two flows of steps  `to run Step11 & Step12, and Step21 & Step22 independently`. This would solve your issue by design: you will have a single run.id for the single job. Otherwise, if a timestamp based incrementer works for you, then you can use it.

Comment: Sorry, I may not have been clear in my question. By independently I meant executing them manually from command line. In my design, I can execute Job1 and Job2 from command line independently, as well they can be executed from parent job when parent job is executed fro command line. In case I replace the two jobs with two flows, I cannot execute flow1 and flow2  from command line.